# get SQL-Statements which uses sort overflows

Tags: sql, database, sorting, db2, db2-luw

Is there a way to find sql-statements which are using sort overflows in DB2?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Also, do you know if it is dynamic-SQL  or static-SQL ?

Comment: The plattform is Linux and it is dynamic-SQL.

Comment: Consider using `dsmtop` or `db2top` or IBM Data Server Manager tools to drill down.  Or via programming use one of Several monitoring table-functions exist that include the `sort_overflows` metric, e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056569.html

Comment: Sorry but i`m new to db2. How do i get the statements (not the number of statements) using MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT_DETAILS?

Comment: If you are new to Db2, why not use the GUI  tools or text-tools as I mentioned above,  for this kind of admin ?

Comment: because we want to get the data via telegraf and save it into an extra database.

Comment: Try `SELECT sort_overflows, substr(stmt_text,1,1024) FROM TABLE(MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT ( 'D', NULL, NULL, -2)) as T WHERE T.sort_overflows > 0 `   (adjust the stubstr arguments to suit your needs)

Answer (score 0):

While snapshots are deprecated they still work.

Make sure the monitors are on, run your workload, then do;

db2 get snapshot for dynamic sql on {dbname}

The sort overflows are shown there.